# How to block EVERYTHING from accessing my computer from the network?

Tags: networking

Brand new Windows 10 Pro user here. I want zero network traffic unless I issued the order of doing it. I am always physically in front of my Computer and have admin Rights.

Comment: If you block everything then you wouldn't be able to "surf and play online games and download data of any kind" so its not clear what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Google search about "firewalls" - that's the closest you'll get to what you want.  If you have a router between your computer and your internet then it likely already has a firewall in it.  Look for Stateful Packet Inspection option in that and enable it if you have it.  Other than that Windows itself may ask if specific programs are allowed to use the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Firewall (or many other software firewalls), you should be able to create an inbound rule to block all inbound traffic (meaning, traffic initiated from another machine) to all protocols.

This is what you'd do to create that rule for Windows Firewall:

- Click Start > Type in "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" > Open it
- Click on Inbound Rules and then New Rule on the right
- Rule Type: Custom
- Program: All Programs
- Protocol and Ports: Any
- Scope: Any IP Address (both local and remote)
- Action: Block the connection
- Profile: All (Domain/Private/Public)
- Name: (Any name you see fit)

Then turn the firewall on if it isn't already.

That said, keep in mind that:

- Just because the PC is blocking all inbound traffic doesn't mean there still aren't any network security concerns with it; there are applications / malware / virii that can still initiate stateful outbound traffic. Having a good antivirus, maybe setting the firewall to "ask" or deny some applications outbound, and having an understanding of what's running on your PC are still a must, in my opinion.
- You might inadvertently block some desired traffic (e.g. file sharing within your home network, ICMP for inbound ping/tracert troubleshooting, etc.)

Comment: So, if I get infected with something, that thing can still communicate with it's owner, even If I'm blocking all inbound traffic? And if I block outbound traffic, it can impersonate as something else and still communicate with it's owner? Well, then I'm screwed because I can't detect the thing I got infected with with any kind of Antivirus or antimalware. I can see different PID's for the same process, but I have yet to find a software that will allow me to filter network traffic by PID.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Process Identifiers when you say PID, Those are generated by the Operating System, and they do change (with a few exceptions)... so I'm not sure why you'd want to block them or how you could determine which one is "bad".